# Group By Not Null with Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a nested (one level) message application which is have a simple "messages" table. Now suppose that this simple table has basic columns like "messageId" and "parentMessageID" for testing purposes.

```
messageId | parentMessageID (FK referencing to messageId)
--------------------------
1         | NULL
2         | 1
3         | NULL
4         | 1
5         | 1
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is to group all messages by their parentMessageID's to show latest messages under the name of their parents. But as you can see, parent messages are not going to have parentMessageID since they are already parents.

```
$messagesRepository->createQueryBuilder('m')->groupBy('m.parentMessageID')->getQuery();
```

This piece of code returns me 2 rows (grouped by nulls and not nulls) but i want 3 rows (grouped by not nulls). Is it possible to have group by NOT NULL field with Doctrine2?